# Maximin for mountain pass theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if there is a maximin version for the Mountain Pass theorem?. In other words, can there exist $c$ such that $c=\underset{\gamma\in\Gamma}\max\underset{u\in\gamma([0,1])}\inf I(u)$?.

In other words, does the following hold? - If $I:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ functional obeying the Palais-Smale condition and $\Gamma:=\{\gamma\in C([0,1]:X)|I(0)=0, I(\gamma(1))>0\}$ and in addition $I(0)=0$, $I(v)<0$ whenever $\|v\|=r$ for some $r>0$, and for some $e$ such that $\|e\|>r$ we have $I(e)>0$, then $c=\underset{\gamma\in\Gamma}\max\underset{u\in\gamma([0,1])}\inf I(u)$.

Is there any reference to such a thing?.

Comment: What are $\Gamma$ and $I$?

Comment: $I:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ functional obeying the Palais Smale condition and $\Gamma=\{\gamma\in C([0,1];X)|I(0)=0, I(\gamma(1))>0$ and in addition $I(0)=0$, $I(v)<0$ for any $\|v\|=r$ for some $r$, and $I(e)>0$ for some $e$ such that $\|e\|>r$.

Comment: I think you should include that in the question.

Comment: I have added it now.